# In JIRA (Greenhopper) how do you directly access the greenhopper stored data to calculate Velocity?

Tags: agile, scrum, jira, greenhopper

I'm trying to use SQL, REST or the Jira Api to find out what the velocity of a project is at any current moment in time. Right now I am trying to find the total number of story points assigned/completed for each sprint and version and from this calculate the velocity of the overall project.

The problem is that Greenhopper is an addon to Jira and does not change the Jira database in anyway, so it must store this information about scrum/agile projects elsewhere. Any ideas where this information might be located?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally worked it out!

So here is some of the techniques that we use to access data from Jira.

### SQL

This SQL statement for example counts all the issues from every point in Jira for each priority.

```
SELECT 
    project.ID AS id,
    project.pkey,
    project.pname AS projectname,
    jiraissue.PRIORITY AS priority,
    COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM jiraissue 
LEFT JOIN project ON jiraissue.PROJECT=project.ID 
GROUP BY project.ID,jiraissue.PRIORITY
ORDER BY project.id
```

Also check out... http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA041/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA

### REST Api

I have not tried this  properly but there is also a set of REST api that you can use to access some of the data from Jira. This documentation is available here: http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

An example link: https://JIRA_LINK/rest/auth/1/session

### Java

Also another useful link for JIRA Java api: http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I use an older version of jira & greenhopper.... but in that version, greenhopper allows you to choose the field you "burndown" by.  In my case it's a field (i believe a custom field) called "Likely".  So it should be there in the DB/API somewhere.  good luck.